# bitshift with Arduino and with RaspberryPi

Tags: python, arduino, bit-shift

I have been testing a piece of hardware I just picked up from Radio-shack (L3G4200D 3 axis Gyroscope) I used the sample code supplied by Parallax on the Arduino to get a idea how to use I2C and the correct buffers to read/write. I want to use this with my Raspberry Pi. I connected the device to the RaspberryPi and now using the Python I2C libraries was writing and reading data but while trying to merge the MSB and LSB together I'm seeing different results. After futher testing on the difference between how the Arduino and RPI's Python code treat the BitShift left I found these results

Aurduino:

```
int msb=255;

Serial.println(msb);
Serial.println(msb,BIN);
Serial.println((msb<<1),BIN);
Serial.println((msb<<2),BIN);
Serial.println((msb<<3),BIN);
Serial.println((msb<<4),BIN);
Serial.println((msb<<5),BIN);
Serial.println((msb<<6),BIN);
Serial.println((msb<<7),BIN);
Serial.println((msb<<8),BIN)
Serial.pringln((msb<<8));
```

Outputs:

```
255
111111110
1111111100
11111111000
111111110000
1111111100000
11111111000000
111111110000000
1111111100000000
111111111111111100000000
-255
```

Python(RaspberryPi)

```
msb = 255
print str(msb)
print bin(msb)
print bin((msb<<1))
print bin((msb<<2))
print bin((msb<<3))
print bin((msb<<4))
print bin((msb<<5))
print bin((msb<<6))
print bin((msb<<7))
print bin((msb<<8))
print (msb<<8)
```

outputs:

```
255
0b11111111
0b111111110
0b1111111100
0b11111111000
0b111111110000
0b1111111100000
0b11111111000000
0b111111110000000
0b1111111100000000
65280
```

Do you see where it all changes? (msb<<8) in the Arduino the results in binary go nuts and adds 8 more 1's. What 24 bits? I don't understand but the Integer returned is -255 a singed integer. Dose Python have a signed 16 bit integer? What I found is Python signs the number separately.

In the end I will be or-ing the msb with the lsb

```
rate = (msb<<8)|lsb
```

Also I could be going a step further to bring this part to my EV3 Lego Mindstorms using Lejos and Java. I guessing that Java will sign the integer as the Arduino does.

Comment: Are you looking to match your Python code with Arduino? Or vice versa? This question is a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to match the results in Python. The Sensor returns two bytes that return positive or negative deg/sec. The trouble is when in python combining the MSB and LSB in python doesn't seem to negate the value using bit 16 as the signed bit. The code I'm tring to replicate in pyhon is found [link]http://learn.parallax.com/KickStart/27911 Botom of page "Arduino"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to make bit 16 the signed bit in my python code

```
msb = 255
lsb = 0

shift=(msb<<8)
if (shift & 0b1000000000000000):
    result=(32768 - ((shfit & 0b0111111111111111) | lsb)) * -1
else:
    result=(shift | lsb)

print (result,bin(msb),bin(lsb))
```

outputs:

```
-256, '0b11111111', '0b00000000'
```

Seems to work with the entire range from -32768 to 32768